# position icons within LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-linearlayout

I've an app where I have 2 icons within a `Linearlayout`. How to position the icons next to each other centrally?

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/buttonsignin"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:background="@drawable/signinbuttonmenu" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/buttongetrota"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:background="@drawable/rotabuttonmenu"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the attribute `android:gravity` with the value of `center_horizontal` (`android:gravity="center_horizontal"`) to the parent `LinearLayout` will do it. Changing the `center_horizontal` to just `center` will set it right in the center both Vertically as well as Horizontally.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonsignin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/signinbuttonmenu" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttongetrota"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/rotabuttonmenu" />
</LinearLayout>
```